# Where can I get pkfuncs.h (and access to KernelIoControl)?

Tags: c++, c, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm trying to call [KernelIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909165.aspx) but can't find the header file pkfuncs.h anywhere.

I'm wondering if:
a) Is there a secret download I need?
b) Or is it not present because the device's SDK I'm using (Casio) does not include these libraries?

Also ... presumably it's WINAPI? I think I'll just dynamically link to it.

Comment: ctacke already gave a solution but here's some extra info: You can find it in platform builder. You use it to compile a windows CE kernel image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my searching I also found [this page](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windowsce.embedded/browse_thread/thread/772dda820f1a5d33/cdb633d1f9c61aff?lnk=st&q=IOCTL_HAL_DDK_CALL%20%20KernelIoControl&pli=1) very useful on getting the IOCTRL_HAL_GET_DEVICEID:

It also details the DEVICE_ID structure, which is necessary to use the call:

```
#define IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICEID CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_HAL, 21, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS) 

typedef struct _DEVICE_ID { 
    DWORD dwSize; 
    DWORD dwPresetIDOffset; 
    DWORD dwPresetIDBytes; 
    DWORD dwPlatformIDOffset; 
    DWORD dwPlatformIDBytes; 
} DEVICE_ID, *PDEVICE_ID;
```

What isn't necessarily obvious is that the data contained at the given offsets are just int values, and probably best viewed as hex codes.

Comment: It documents it ... but not well! It doesn't tell you the format of the data you'll be getting. char, WCHAR, integers? But thanks for including the link as it adds to the info.

Comment: Yep, it's not well documented beyound what you see becasue Microsoft doesn't dictate what it should return.  The OEM can return really anything they want from it - char, wchar, bytes, a struct - anything.  Typically it's just a number.

Comment: ah I see. Perhaps they should dictate that if we are to generically handle such a call!? Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the header to call KernelIoControl.  Just add this to your own app:

```
extern "C" BOOL KernelIoControl(
  DWORD dwIoControlCode,
  LPVOID lpInBuf,
  DWORD nInBufSize,
  LPVOID lpOutBuf,
  DWORD nOutBufSize,
  LPDWORD lpBytesReturned
);
```

The linker will find it for you.

Comment: cool. The linker can't find me the value of IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICEID though! ... do you know it?

Comment: It's `#define IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICEID CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_HAL, 21, 
METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)` which compiles down to a value of `0x01010054`

Answer (score -1):

Here is code that I use to get a unique device ID:

```
PDWORD      pdwTmp;
DWORD       dwUIDLen;
DWORD       dwLen;
DWORD       dwIdx;
BYTE        abData[512];
BYTE        abID[64];
PDEVICE_ID  pDvcID;

dwLen = 0;
memset(abID, 0, sizeof(abID));
memset(abData, 0, sizeof(abData));
pDvcID = (PDEVICE_ID) abData;
pDvcID->dwSize = sizeof(abData);
KernelIoControl(IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICEID, NULL, 0, abData, sizeof(abData), &dwLen);
// If valid data was returned build ID from both parts
if ( (dwLen >= (sizeof(*pDvcID) + 8))       // Enough bytes returned for struct and 8 ID bytes
    && (dwLen >= pDvcID->dwSize)            // Bytes returned is at least indicated struct size
    && pDvcID->dwPresetIDBytes && pDvcID->dwPlatformIDBytes     // Both ID's are present
    && (pDvcID->dwPresetIDOffset >= sizeof(*pDvcID))            // Preset ID offset is reasonable
    && (pDvcID->dwPlatformIDOffset >= sizeof(*pDvcID))          // Platform ID offset is reasonable
    && ((pDvcID->dwPresetIDOffset + pDvcID->dwPresetIDBytes)    // Preset ID is in bounds
        <= pDvcID->dwSize)
    && ((pDvcID->dwPlatformIDOffset + pDvcID->dwPlatformIDBytes)// Platform ID is in bounds
        <= pDvcID->dwSize) )
{
    // Copy as much of the Preset ID as will fit
    dwIdx = pDvcID->dwPresetIDBytes;
    if ( dwIdx > sizeof(abID) )
        dwIdx = sizeof(abID);
    if ( dwIdx )
        memcpy(abID, abData + pDvcID->dwPresetIDOffset, dwIdx);
    dwLen = dwIdx;
    // Copy as much of the Platform ID as will fit
    dwIdx = pDvcID->dwPlatformIDBytes;
    if ( dwIdx > (sizeof(abID) - dwLen) )
        dwIdx = (sizeof(abID) - dwLen);
    if ( dwIdx )
        memcpy(abID + dwLen, abData + pDvcID->dwPlatformIDOffset, dwLen);
    dwLen += dwIdx;
}
```